# The IControllerFactory 'MefContrib.Web.Mvc.CompositionControllerFactory' did not return a controller for the name 'Home'

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, generics, c#-4.0, dependency-injection, mef

I'm new to DI via ASP.NET MVC 3. and I'm using `mefcontrib` as my DI container. I install the `mefcontrib` and `mefcontrib.mvc3` via nuget. and when I try to run the project, I get this error:

> The IControllerFactory
>   'MefContrib.Web.Mvc.CompositionControllerFactory' did not return a
>   controller for the name 'Home'.

I googled the error and search and search again. but I can't find anything! can everybody help me please? here is the `App_Start` content created by nuget automatically:

```
[assembly: WebActivator.PreApplicationStartMethod(typeof(AlamKouh.UI.App_Start.AppStart_MefContribMVC3), "Start")]

namespace AlamKouh.UI.App_Start
{
    using System.ComponentModel.Composition.Hosting;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web.Mvc;
    using MefContrib.Hosting.Conventions;
    using MefContrib.Web.Mvc;

    public static class AppStart_MefContribMVC3
    {
        public static void Start()
        {
            CompositionContainerLifetimeHttpModule.Register();

            var catalog = new AggregateCatalog(
                new DirectoryCatalog("bin"),
                new ConventionCatalog(new MvcApplicationRegistry()));

            var dependencyResolver = new CompositionDependencyResolver(catalog);
            DependencyResolver.SetResolver(dependencyResolver);

            ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(
                new CompositionControllerFactory(
                    new CompositionControllerActivator(dependencyResolver)));

            FilterProviders.Providers.Remove(FilterProviders.Providers.Single(f => f is FilterAttributeFilterProvider));
            FilterProviders.Providers.Add(new CompositionFilterAttributeFilterProvider(dependencyResolver));

            ModelValidatorProviders.Providers.Remove(ModelValidatorProviders.Providers.OfType<DataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider>().Single());
            ModelValidatorProviders.Providers.Add(
                new CompositionDataAnnotationsModelValidatorProvider(dependencyResolver));

            ModelBinderProviders.BinderProviders.Add(
                new CompositionModelBinderProvider(dependencyResolver));
        }
    }
}
```

and this is my HomeController:

```
namespace AlamKouh.UI.Controllers {

    public interface ITest<T> { }

    [Export(typeof(ITest<>))]
    public class Test<T> : ITest<T> { }

    public class HomeController : Controller {

        private readonly ITest<string> _test;

        [ImportingConstructor]
        public HomeController(ITest<string> test) {
            _test = test;
        }

        public ActionResult Index() {
            var t = _test;
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

@Yorgo suggest me to switch to `StructureMap` and I do it. `StructureMap` is easier for me, so I accept @Yorgo's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best and fastest DI container is StructureMap. I suggest you to use it. If you wanna use it, i can help you for configurations

Comment: did StructureMap support open generics?

Comment: I switch to `StructureMap` :D and my problem resolved for now. But if I need your help, I will send you my question. Thanks in advanced for presenting `StructureMap`. Regards.